# Как лучше сделать обработку ошибки в данном случае? Бот вк LongPoll

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, бот

У меня всего два вопроса

Как сделать обработку ошибки в команде /id? В данном варианте я беру из массива текст, но хочу если был найден reply_message брать оттуда from_id. /id @id либо /id ( пересланное сообщение)

```
const token = "";
const VkBot = require("node-vk-bot-api"),
bot = new VkBot(token);

bot.command("/id", (msg) => {

Если найдено msg.message.reply_massage.from_id то присваивать его переменной id иначе
let text = msg.message.text;
let id = text.substring(text.indexOf("[") + 1, text.lastIndexOf("|"));

msg.reply(id)
});

bot.startPolling()
```

Answer (score 0):

typeof obj['from_id'] != "undefined"

если ключ from_id найден в пересланном сообщение, то let id = msg.message.reply_message.from_id

иначе при ошибке
let text = msg.message.text;

let id = text.substring(text.indexOf("[") + 1, text.lastIndexOf("|"));

```
bot.command("/id", (msg) => {

let obj = msg.message.reply_message
try {if (typeof obj['from_id'] != "undefined") {console.log('Сообщение пересланное');
let id = msg.message.reply_message.from_id; msg.reply('id' + id) }} catch (err) {console.log('Обычное сообщение');

let text = msg.message.text;
let id = text.substring(text.indexOf("[") + 1, text.lastIndexOf("|"));
msg.reply(id)}  
});
}

msg.reply(id)
});
```